# Node.js api rate limiting with multiple rate limits

Tags: node.js, api, npm, rate-limiting

I'm working on an application that hits a public API many times. However, the API has multiple rate limits that my application must satisfy.

The rate limit is
20 requests every 1 second
AND
100 requests every 2 minutes.

I've been looking for some rate limiting packages, but all of them seem to only be able to set a single rate limit. I could set the rate limit to 20 requests per second, but then I could make 100 requests over 5 seconds and violate the second limit. I could also set the rate limit to 100 requests every 2 minutes, but that will immediately violate the first limit. Is there some package that could help me achieve meeting both rate limits?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you must hit it as often as possible?

Comment: I think that limiting the number of times a function can be called with that logic can be achieved with 5 lines of code. Why do you want an already built library for this purpose?

Comment: @Deadron A user will need to hit the api about 50 times, so if you were implying just setting the rate limit to something like 5/6 requests per second (to match both the first and second criteria), then that would take too long.

Comment: @lilezek I'm not familiar with how to limit a function to meet the criteria in that way, do you mind showing me or linking me to an example of how to do so? That would be great if it were really simple.

Comment: @Andrew I can't because it is really basic JavaScript programming involving Date. Just look for `debounce`.

Comment: [rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) should be easy for that

Comment: [rateman](https://github.com/vilic/rateman) supports exactly what you need (multi-window rate limiting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [this express middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit), you can set 2 limits along the lines of:

```
var RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

var apiLimiterSeconds = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: 1, // 1 second
  max: 20,
  delayMs: 0 // disabled 
});

var apiLimiterMinutes = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: 2*60, // 2 minutes
  max: 100,
  delayMs: 0 // disabled 
});

// only apply to requests that begin with /api/ 
app.use('/api/', apiLimiterSeconds);
app.use('/api/', apiLimiterMinutes);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this will work. I saw this package earlier but didn't think to apply several rate limits to my application.